# REVISTED$^1$ - Order: Modular Arithmetic

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, limits, modular-arithmetic

### Relevant Literature:

[image]

### Question:

Observe that $2^{10}=1024≡−1 \pmod{25}$.Find the order of $2$ modulo $25$.

Thoughts:

Direct answers are OK, but I'd like to know if I'm right that what I'm really looking for is this:
$$\inf\left\{\frac{2^x-2}{25}~:~x\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}\right\}$$

### EDIT$^1$:

What I meant was, I'm trying to find the smallest such $x$ so that $2^{10}+25k+2=2^x$, where $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. How do I write that in $\inf$ terms?

### EDIT$^2$:

Am I right in thinking that I could think of it this way too:

$$ \inf{\{\log_2(2^{10}+25x+2)~:~x\in \mathbb{Z}\}} $$

Comment: No, that infimum is simply $0$. You’re looking for $$\inf\{n\in\Bbb Z^+:2^n\equiv 1\pmod{25}\}=\inf\{n\in\Bbb Z^+:25\mid 2^n-1\}\;.$$ HINT: What’s $(-1)^2$ modulo $25$?

Comment: What? How can that be zero if $0$ is not even allowable? That "\" is a set minus meaning I'm not including it.

Comment: I know. But $$\frac{2^1-2}{25}=0$$ and is the smallest member of that set.

Comment: That's right, sorry.

Comment: So how does $\inf{}$ work?

Comment: For any $S\subseteq\Bbb R$, $\inf S$ is by definition the greatest lower bound of $S$. Your set is a set of non-negative real numbers, so it’s bounded below by $0$, and $0$ is in the set, so $0$ is its greatest lower bound.

Comment: That inf would be zero at $x=1$. But another reason this idea goes nowhere is that $(2^x-2)/25$ increases very rapidly, and is too large to end up being the order of $2$ mod 25, which by the "Observe that" remark must be a divisor of $20$. Another thing is that you want $2^x$ to be $1$ mod 25, not $2$. What your expression is calculating is the other factor, i.e. the quotient, which is expectedly large, at $x=20$ it is $41943$.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that I'm trying to find smallest such $x$ so that $\frac{2^x-2}{25}$ is an integer.

Comment: Then you have your set notation backwards. You mean $$\inf\left\{n\in\Bbb Z^+:25\mid 2^n-2\right\}\;.$$ This is almost right, but you should have $2^n-1$.

Comment: @BarisaBarukh This is on the right track, however the 2 should be a 1. You want the smallest positive $x$ so that \frac{2^x-1}{25}$ is an integer.

Comment: @coffeemath I know, but I was using the fact that for $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$ and $a'\equiv b'\pmod{m}$, then $a+b\equiv a'+b' \pmod{m}$, so because $2^{10}\equiv -1\pmod{25}$ and $25k+2\equiv 2\pmod{m}$, then $2^{10}+25k+2\equiv 1\pmod{25}$, right?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Hello!

Comment: Yes, $2^{10}+25k+2\equiv 1\pmod{25}$, but I don’t see that this is very helpful, and it doesn’t justify your $2^x-2$. André’s hint is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** The order is $\le 20$, since $2^{20}\equiv (-1)^2\pmod{25}$.  And the order divides $20$, but does not divide $10$. That does not leave many possibilities to rule out.

Comment: Perhaps you are rude person.

Comment: Perhaps you are not.